# Keyword only parameter

Tags: python

Reference http://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-parameter

**keyword-only parameter**: specifies an argument that can be supplied only by keyword. Keyword-only parameters can be defined by including a **single var-positional parameter** or bare * in the parameter list of the function definition before them, for example kw_only1 and kw_only2 in the following:

```
def func(arg, *, kw_only1, kw_only2):
```

Instead of single var-positional parameter shouldn't that be single var-keyword parameter?
Maybe i understood something wrong ...

Answer (score 16):

No, you must use either the `*` *bare* parameter, or use a single `*args` parameter, called a *var-positional parameter* (see the next item in that glossary entry). By adding it to your function signature you force any parameters that follow it to be keyword-only parameters.

So the function signature could be:

```
def func(positional_arg1, *variable_args, kw_only1, kw_only2):
```

and `variable_args` will capture any extra *positional* arguments passed to the function, or you could use:

```
def func(positional_arg1, *, kw_only1, kw_only2):
```

and the function will not support extra positional arguments beyond the first one.

In both cases, you can set `kw_only1` and `kw_only2` *only* by using them as keyword arguments when calling `func()`. Without default values (no `=<expression>` in their definition) they are still *required* arguments.