# What does * in function args and -> after function signature mean?

Tags: python-3.x

I am not familiar with all the python3's new syntax from python2. I have encountered other people's code with this coding pattern.

```
def foo(*, a: str, b: str, c: str) -> baz:
  ...
  ret = baz()
  return ret.myFunc()
```

1. What does * mean in this context?
2. What is the role of baz in this function? Is it another object we passed into foo?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-parameter  and https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html .

Comment: related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22248396/keyword-only-parameter, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53797057/star-as-an-argument-in-python-function, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557920/what-are-type-hints-in-python-3-5 .